# How to find each edge and lines with HoughLinesP() in OpenCV and Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, edge-detection, houghlinesp

So, I have been trying to detect edges using the HoughLinesP() but instead of getting the accurate lines and their end points, my output is kind of lacking from what I need.

```
image = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\Jimit\\Desktop\\Project\\Original Images\\Original Capture.jpg')


#Hough Line Detection. 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 100, 150)
minLineLength = 200
maxLineGap = 100

lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 30, minLineLength, maxLineGap)
for line in lines:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
    cv2.line(image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    print(line)

for theta in lines:
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    print(a)
    print(b)

cv2.imshow('ab', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: Original Image]
[image: Output Image]
[image: Endpoints in shell.]

> As you can see from the images and shell output, I am unable to receive the accurate lines. Moreover, my code seems to fail in capturing the vertical lines.

Comment: The `Canny` method returns one pixel wide lines, which in your case aren't completely straight, thus `HoughLinesP` has problems finding the proper "lines" in your image. Dilating the `Canny` result should work, e.g. adding `edges = cv2.dilate(edges, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3)))` after your `Canny` operation. Also set `minLineLength = 50`, and `maxLineGap = 10`, to find the vertical "lines". That worked for me and the given example.

Comment: @HanHirse I did what you suggested but the result should be **4 list** with **4 tuples** exactly. I am getting like around _10 lists_ which basically means that there are multiple lines over one edge.

Comment: You won't get a perfect result like this, since the shape in the image is distorted, and not a perfect rectangle. Either do something different than `HoughLinesP` (do you explicitly need the **lines** or does the contour suffice?), or do some manual merging of the line segments.

Comment: @HansHirse I am actually using the `HoughLinesP()` to find the **4 thetas** so that I can rotate it and then find the corners using the  `HarrisCorner` for my project. Any other suggestion?

Comment: If you're really just interested in the corners, why not using [`cornerHarris`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#gac1fc3598018010880e370e2f709b4345) directly on your grayscale image? I followed [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/dc/d0d/tutorial_py_features_harris.html), and got the four corners out-of-the-box.

Comment: @HansHirse Well, the main purpose to use `HoughLinesP()` is because the object you see in the image is not fixed-placed. Also, I am trying to find the real time dimensions of the object using **Pixels-Per-Millimeter** ratio. My calculation changes when I place the object in different positions.That is why I am trying to use `cv2.HoughLinesP()` to figure out the theta and rotate such that it matches my **PPM**. I am using `cv2.norm()` but it needs to be manually done for the number of corners the object has. I am kind of stuck on how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191441/discussion-between-jimit-vaghela-and-hanshirse).